# $(data).find returning 0, data.search not helpful

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

im trying to use the $(data).find method to find how many items are in a list located on a page i am calling by AJAX. The $(data) returns

```
jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[145]
[0 … 99]
[100 … 144]
length: 145
__proto__: Object[0]
```

This is not very helpful and shows a nested view when one of the items are expanded ie:

```
[0 … 99]
0: text
1: meta
2: meta
3: meta
4: meta
5: meta
```

and so on.

Because the list populates via javascript itself, the items located in the page source are stored in a var. therefore using $(data).find("WPQ6ListData") simply returns []

using body without jquery, it returns everything, using data.search("WPQ6ListData") returns 109814. So I know it exists and can be used. substringing the by the number from search returns my variable, the whole variable inside the body is

```
var WPQ6ListData = { "Row" : 
[{
"ID": "1",
"PermMask": "0x7fffffffffffffff",
"FSObjType": "0",
"Body1": "test",
"Title": "test",
"FileLeafRef": "1_.000",
"Created_x0020_Date.ifnew": "",
"FileRef": "\u002fsites\u002fResilient\u002fLists\u002fNewsSliderList\u002f1_.000",
"File_x0020_Type": "",
"File_x0020_Type.mapapp": "",
"HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon": "",
"HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapico": "icgen.gif",
"ContentTypeId": "0x0100B87D22D691BA4B419255256292F918AA00B2962D0F358E9442AFF496C5DFF6AB1F"
}
```

The idea of this is to check whether the current elements stored inside are different to what is returned (meaning an item has been added to the list). I cant even use Jquery's load however as it is making the whole page white. and removing the  elements from the page.

is there any way i can return the var as a whole, then reload what is in the GAC for the vars

Comment: This is JSON. We don't use .find() in JSON. Can you show your JS code including your ajax call.

Comment: how do i get it then?

Comment: There seems to be a lot missing from this question. It looks like `data` is an array, but an array of what? And what is this `search()` function -- neither Javascript nor jQuery define that function, is it part of a library you are using?

Comment: Another comment... It sounds like you are trying to load a remote HTML page, which contains a whole bunch of inline Javascript, and then parse that Javascript to determine what variables the page is defining? If so, I think you might want to think about the architecture involved. Perhaps allowing your server code to return JSON responses directly would help.

Comment: no library, search is javascript that returns the index on a string query:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

its an array of everything in a sharepoint webpage, i want to cut it down and then compare the returns of my variable